# Vim にペーストすると改行の数が多くなってしまいます

Tags: vim

秀丸やWindowsメモ帳やブラウザのコピペのテキストをPuTTYのVimでコピペすると（右クリック）改行の数が多くなってしまいます。Vimの設定をすべて空白にすると普通にコピペされます。

設定はこちらです

```
~/.vimrc
1 set number
2 set title
3 set ambiwidth=double
4 set tabstop=4
5 set expandtab
6 set shiftwidth=4
7 set smartindent
8 set list
9 set listchars=tab:»-,trail:-,eol:↲,extends:»,precedes:«,nbsp:%
10 set nrformats-=octal
11 set hidden
12 set history=50
13 set virtualedit=block
14 set whichwrap=b,s,[,],<,>
15 set backspace=indent,eol,start
16 set wildmenu
17 set display=lastline↲
18 set pumheight=10↲
19 set showmatch
20 set matchtime=1
21 set encoding=utf-8
22 set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
```

[image: 画像の説明をここここに入力]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

vim は自動インデント機能を持ったテキストエディタです。mintty のペースト等は文字をキーとしてそのまま貼り付けますので、改行コードが来た際に vim が自動インデントを行います。よって期待しない結果となります。

vim ではこの自動インデントを一時的に無効にする為のオプションが用意されています。

```
:set paste
```

これを実行した後でインサートモードからペーストすると正しくペーストされるはずです。
またいちいちメンドクサイという事であれば

```
:set pastetoggle=<f2>
```

の様にペーストモードに移る専用のキーを定義出来、押すとペーストモードがトグルして切り替わります。